# SSRS Scanning Paramters in another separate report for an IIF statement

Tags: reporting-services

I would really love some help with this problem...

I am making a dashboard of a variety of sites and a variety of parameters. Am I able to make an iif statement using filenames of other reports?

I want to check all of the parameters of other filenames (the other reports) to see if any of the cells have a limit breach. If one cells has a limit breach, I want this to come through to the parent report (Dashboard) into the cells as "NOT PASS". Currently I am using

IIF(IsLimitBreached =True , "Not PASS", IIF(IsLimitBreached =False , "PASS", "Option 3 Text here"))

however, this does NOT cover an entire site area.

Related pictures in the comments

Comment: This is a matrix of a bunch of sites for one locality. The green cells represent a pass. Red is a not Pass. If there is a single Not pass or red cell for the entire locality file, I want a "Not Pass" showing up in the higher level report.  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sUXK6.jpg

Comment: this is a snippet of my test Dashboard.  
[1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UxqK2.jpg

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking ? Does the locality report and task dashboard are same report and two tablix or the two seprate reports ? And the datasets are same or the same for both reports

Comment: both report types have the same Data sets, but the reports are many different files. The Dashboard links to many locality matrices. I.E there are many different files in the same layout as the picture in the first comment, and the test dashboard (The picture in the second comment) links to many locality reports.